# Error testing a method that throws an Error in Quick with Nimble

Tags: swift, quick-nimble

I'm having a problem getting a Nimble matcher correct in testing a method that throws an exception.  According to the docs it should be simple.  I just need an expectation like this

```
expect( try somethingThatThrows() ).toNot( throwError() )
```

However with Swift 3 and Xcode 8.2 I'm getting a compiler editor.  Here's the context.

```
describe("Using RealmDatasource") {

   let datastore = RealmDatasource() as Datasource

       it("can retrieve an object") {

           expect( try datastore.getCurrentObject() ).to( throwError() )

       }

}
```

I get the following error on the 'it' declaration line

> ```
> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() -> () throws to non-throwing function of type '() -> ()'
> ```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try using expect with curly brackets  { }

`expect { try datastore.getCurrentObject() }.to( throwError() )`

should be working